# DSum with Date criteria and GROUP BY

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, group-by, sum

I want to write an access query (I thought SQL would be most appropriate) in order to retrieve for each product a single figure OR the sum of figures if these figures are bound to a similar date.

My tables look like this:

```
Tck1    DeD1    Bdf1
Tck1    DeD2    Bdf2
Tck1    DeD3    Bdf3
Tck2    DeD1    Bdf1
Tck2    DeD1    Bdf2
Tck2    DeD1    Bdf3
Tck2    DeD2    Bdf4
Tck3    DeD1    Bdf1
Tck3    DeD2    Bdf2
```

As you can see, for Tck1 and Tck2 I would only need to retrieve Bdf1 but for Tck2 I would need to sum Bdf1, Bdf2 and Bdf3

I have tried (unsuccessfully) a few statements:

```
SELECT Sum([tblB].Bdf) As SumOfBdf
FROM [tblB]
GROUP BY Tck
HAVING (DeD = Min(Ded));
```

As well as:

```
SELECT Sum([tblB].Bdf) As Expr1
FROM [tblB]
GROUP BY Tck
HAVING (DeD = Min(Ded));
```

Any idea what I should change to pull the data? Thanks

**THANKS** to all of you who had a look at it, esp Gord.

**Here is the answer in a single statement:**

```
SELECT tblB.Tck, tblB.DeD, Sum(tblB.Bdf) AS SumOfBdf
FROM tblB
GROUP BY tblB.Tck, tblB.DeD
HAVING (((tblB.DeD) In (SELECT Min(tblB.DeD) AS MinOfDeD FROM tblB GROUP BY tblB.Tck;)));
```

Comment: You should add your tables structures to the question. And I don't understand the part where you say: "OR the sum of figures if these figures are bound to a similar date." - Do you want this in the same query as the sum of figures for each product? In different queries it is quite simple.

Comment: +1 for the comment from @FilipeSilva - Also, some representative sample data and an example of the desired result is always helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your data looks something like this:

```
ID  Tck   DeD         Bdf
--  ----  ----------  ---
 1  Tck1  2013-01-01  100
 2  Tck1  2013-01-02  101
 3  Tck1  2013-01-03  102
 4  Tck2  2013-02-01  201
 5  Tck2  2013-02-01  202
 6  Tck2  2013-02-01  203
 7  Tck2  2013-02-02  204
 8  Tck3  2013-03-01  301
 9  Tck3  2013-03-02  302
```

then a query to return the earliest date for each [Tck] would be

```sql
SELECT Tck, Min(DeD) AS MinOfDeD FROM tblB GROUP BY Tck
```

That gives us

```
Tck   MinOfDeD  
----  ----------
Tck1  2013-01-01
Tck2  2013-02-01
Tck3  2013-03-01
```

The next step is to use that query as a subquery to isolate the rows that belong to those dates

```sql
SELECT tblB.Tck, tblB.DeD, tblB.Bdf
FROM
    tblB
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT Tck, Min(DeD) AS MinOfDeD FROM tblB GROUP BY Tck
    ) AS minDates
        ON tblB.Tck = minDates.Tck AND tblB.DeD = minDates.MinOfDeD
```

which returns

```
Tck   DeD         Bdf
----  ----------  ---
Tck1  2013-01-01  100
Tck2  2013-02-01  201
Tck2  2013-02-01  202
Tck2  2013-02-01  203
Tck3  2013-03-01  301
```

Finally, we can wrap that in an aggregation query to give us the sums

```sql
SELECT Tck, DeD, Sum(Bdf) AS SumOfBdf
FROM
    (
        SELECT tblB.Tck, tblB.DeD, tblB.Bdf
        FROM
            tblB
            INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT Tck, Min(DeD) AS MinOfDeD FROM tblB GROUP BY Tck
            ) AS minDates
                ON tblB.Tck = minDates.Tck AND tblB.DeD = minDates.MinOfDeD
    )
GROUP BY Tck, DeD
```

returning

```
Tck   DeD         SumOfBdf
----  ----------  --------
Tck1  2013-01-01       100
Tck2  2013-02-01       606
Tck3  2013-03-01       301
```

### Edit re: comment

If we tweak the test data slightly:

```
ID  Tck   DeD         Bdf
--  ----  ----------  ---
 1  Tck1  2013-01-01  100
 2  Tck1  2013-01-02  101
 3  Tck1  2013-01-03  102
 4  Tck2  2013-01-02  201
```

then the query in your comment (and updated question)

```sql
SELECT tblB.Tck, tblB.DeD, Sum(tblB.Bdf) AS SumOfBdf 
FROM tblB 
GROUP BY tblB.Tck, tblB.DeD 
HAVING (((tblB.DeD) In (SELECT Min(tblB.DeD) AS MinOfDeD FROM tblB GROUP BY tblB.Tck;)));
```

returns two rows for 'Tck1'

```
Tck   DeD         SumOfBdf
----  ----------  --------
Tck1  2013-01-01       100
Tck1  2013-01-02       101
Tck2  2013-01-02       201
```

because the HAVING clause does not distinguish Min(dates) by [Tck]

The last query in my answer above this edit (which *does* provide the solution in "one query", albeit one that uses a couple of subqueries), returns

```
Tck   DeD         SumOfBdf
----  ----------  --------
Tck1  2013-01-01       100
Tck2  2013-01-02       201
```

Comment: Thanks Gord, that's what I was looking for and I was hoping to get it done whith one single statement... which is the following:  SELECT tblB.Tck, tblB.DeD, Sum(tblB.Bdf) AS SumOfBdf

FROM tblB

GROUP BY tblB.Tck, tblB.DeD

HAVING (((tblB.DeD) In (SELECT Min(tblB.DeD) AS MinOfDeD FROM tblB GROUP BY tblB.Tck;)));

Comment: @ProtoVB I'm not sure that your query will always return what you want. I have updated my answer to illustrate.

Comment: Thanks Gord for highlighting this element. I will run some tests